# Android Widget RemoteView ImageButton setImageSource

Tags: android, widget

Would like to use an Image button in my widget layout.  I want an image that is clickable, so clicking on image will change the image.  Not sure how to set this up in WidgetProvider RemoteView.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Specifically how to change the image from within onReceive in the Widget provider? Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Specifically how to change the image from within onReceive in the Widget provider?

Call `setImageViewBitmap()`, `setImageViewResource()`, or `setImageViewResource()` on the `RemoteViews` in your `onUpdate()` method, or in the `IntentService` you invoke from the `onUpdate()` method, or anywhere else you are using `AppWidgetManager` to update the app widget.